# Build a new data frame from existing data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Suppose I have the following data frame df_week that gives details about jobs in departments every week:

```
Week Department Job Value
1    A          a1  10
1    A          a2  12
2    B          b1  9
3    A          a1  14
3    C          c1  8
4    A          a2  9
5    B          b1  13
5    B          b2  13
5    D          d1  7
5    E          e1  8
```

Now I also have another data frame df_job that gives some information about the jobs themselves:

```
Job Days
a1  5
a2  3
b1  3
b2  2
b3  3
b4  5
c1  3
c2  2
c3  4
d1  4
d2  6
e1  2
e2  3
e3  2
```

What I would like to do is to build a new data frame that lists out all of the job details each week, like this:

```
Week Department Job Value Days
1    A          a1  10    5
1    A          a2  12    3 
1    B          b1  NA    3
1    B          b2  NA    2
1    B          b3  NA    3
1    B          b4  NA    5
1    C          c1  NA    3
1    C          c2  NA    2
1    C          c3  NA    4
1    D          d1  NA    4
1    D          d2  NA    6
1    E          e1  NA    2
2    A          a1  NA    5
2    A          a2  NA    3 
2    B          b1  9     3
2    B          b2  NA    2
2    B          b3  NA    3
2    B          b4  NA    5
2    C          c1  NA    3
2    C          c2  NA    2
2    C          c3  NA    4
2    D          d1  NA    4
2    D          d2  NA    6
2    E          e1  NA    2
3    A          a1  14    5
3    A          a2  NA    3 
3    B          b1  NA    3
3    B          b2  NA    2
3    B          b3  NA    3
3    B          b4  NA    5
3    C          c1  8     3
3    C          c2  NA    2
3    C          c3  NA    4
3    D          d1  NA    4
3    D          d2  NA    6
3    E          e1  NA    2
4    A          a1  9     5
4    A          a2  NA    3 
4    B          b1  NA    3
4    B          b2  NA    2
4    B          b3  NA    3
4    B          b4  NA    5
4    C          c1  NA    3
4    C          c2  NA    2
4    C          c3  NA    4
4    D          d1  NA    4
4    D          d2  NA    6
4    E          e1  NA    2
5    A          a1  NA    5
5    A          a2  NA    3 
5    B          b1  13    3
5    B          b2  13    2
5    B          b3  NA    3
5    B          b4  NA    5
5    C          c1  NA    3
5    C          c2  NA    2
5    C          c3  NA    4
5    D          d1  7     4
5    D          d2  NA    6
5    E          e1  8     2
```

My thinking was that I would have to replicate df_job by the number of weeks in df_week, and then somehow use the merge function to do a join. But this does not seem to work since the elements in the id (job) are not unique, and how do I get the missing data represented?

Comment: why do the values contained in jobs that don't happen during a certain week need to be filled in with NA? As of right now, the first two dataframes don't seem to have the information required to make the third one. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @sjp the NAs would represent jobs not being completed for that particular week. What exactly is missing from the first two dataframes?

Comment: You have to have some way of coding in the fact that if a job doesn't happen in a given week it's value is NA. If you `merge` the dataframes by `Job` as they are you can either have a dataset the same as `df_week` but with the `Days` column for the rows that exist in `df_week` *or* you can have all of the jobs but the `week` column won't fill in correctly, and information will be duplicated incorrectly.

Comment: Well, there's an exhaustive list of jobs that needs duplicated every week. Can we first create an initial dataframe with this replication and then populate the dataframe whenever the job happens for that week?

Comment: My issue was just that you needed the df_jobs replicated for each week, and to merge the dataframes by both job and week. Ronak has solved that nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replicate the rows of `df_job` using number of unique weeks in  `df_week`. Create a `Week` column and join the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- n_distinct(df_week$Week)

df_job %>%
  tidyr::uncount(n) %>%
  mutate(Week  = rep(1:n, length.out = n())) %>%
  left_join(df_week, by = c('Job', 'Week'))

#   Job Days Week Department Value
#1   a1    5    1          A    10
#2   a2    3    1          A    12
#3   b1    3    1       <NA>    NA
#4   b2    2    1       <NA>    NA
#5   b3    3    1       <NA>    NA
#6   b4    5    1       <NA>    NA
#7   c1    3    1       <NA>    NA
#8   c2    2    1       <NA>    NA
#9   c3    4    1       <NA>    NA
#10  d1    4    1       <NA>    NA
#11  d2    6    1       <NA>    NA
#12  e1    2    1       <NA>    NA
#13  e2    3    1       <NA>    NA
#14  e3    2    1       <NA>    NA
#15  a1    5    2       <NA>    NA
#16  a2    3    2       <NA>    NA
#17  b1    3    2          B     9
#...
#...
```